# How to make a Quiz with only Bootstrap, don't use javascript?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a quiz like this http://vnexpress.net/tin-tuc/giao-duc/hoc-tieng-anh/trac-nghiem-cum-dong-tu-voi-look-3478037.html

This quiz use the elements of Bootstrap with no javascript

Thank for your support, and im so sorry if my english is bad :(

Answer (score 0):

The quiz in the provided link does use javascript. You just need to look at the source to see this.

Bootstrap will only help you with the design and layout of the quiz.

Check out this link, perhaps they can help you get an understanding of what you need.

```
[Demo Link](http://codepen.io/gcarino/pen/LDgtn)
```